# DirectX11 mapping vertex without using memcpy

Tags: c++, directx-11

apparently I have some issue regarding mapping vertexBuffers into the GPU using memcpy

This is my initial code

```
  D3D11_MAPPED_SUBRESOURCE MappedResource;
  ID3D11Buffer *pBuffer = s_vertexBuffers.pBuffers[i].Get();
  HRESULT hr = s_d3dContext->Map(pBuffer, 0, D3D11_MAP_WRITE_DISCARD, 0, &MappedResource);

  float *vertices = (float *) MappedResource.pData,
        *data = (float *)s_vertexBuffers.pData[i];
  int len = s_vertexBuffers.pStrides[i];
  if (i != VERTEX_BUFFER::COLOR)
  {
      len *= total;
  }

  memcpy(vertices, data, len);
  s_d3dContext->Unmap(pBuffer, 0);
```

What I'm going to change is the way of mapping (copying data from buffers into GPU) using pointer, like the one pointed on [here](http://rastertek.com/dx11tut05.html) into something similar to SetShaderParameters function (also on the tutorial), which is using pointer to get the data in the  buffer and copying data directly using pointer into it

Basically, line 
float *vertices = (float *) MappedResource.pData
until 
memcpy(vertices, data, len);

will be changed into something like the above tutorial pointed out

This is what my code looks like right now

```
VertexBuffers *dataPtr;
dataPtr = (VertexBuffers *)MappedResource.pData;
dataPtr->pBuffers[i] = s_vertexBuffers.pBuffers[i].Get();
dataPtr->pData[i] = s_vertexBuffers.pData[i];
dataPtr->pSizes[i] = s_vertexBuffers.pSizes[i];
dataPtr->pStrides[i] = s_vertexBuffers.pStrides[i];
if (i != VERTEX_BUFFER::COLOR) 
{
   dataPtr->pStrides[i] *= total;
}
```

struct VertexBuffers and VERTEX_BUFFER namespace content is

```
namespace VERTEX_BUFFER
{
    enum : int
    {
        POSITION,
        COLOR,
        TEXCOORD,
        COUNT
    };
}


 struct VertexBuffers
    {
        ComPtr<ID3D11Buffer>    pBuffers[VERTEX_BUFFER::COUNT];
        void*                   pData[VERTEX_BUFFER::COUNT];
        UINT                    pStrides[VERTEX_BUFFER::COUNT];
        UINT                    pSizes[VERTEX_BUFFER::COUNT];
    };
```

I think the problem is whenever I'm trying to copy data using pointer, I'm not taking len into account like memcpy does

Since I'm currently learning DirectX and programming please do correct me if something quite not right about my explanations.

Sorry for the bad code and bad programming skills, and also for the bad english, Cheers!

Comment: Very hard to understand what you are trying to do. Maybe if you include a link to the tutorial you are following it will help.

Comment: http://www.rastertek.com/dx11tut05.html I'm going to make my code into something similar to SetShaderParameters function in the link provided, Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you want something like this?

```
VertexBuffers *dataPtr;
dataPtr = (VertexBuffers *)MappedResource.pData;
dataPtr->pBuffers[i] = s_vertexBuffers.pBuffers[i].Get();
dataPtr->pSizes[i] = s_vertexBuffers.pSizes[i];
dataPtr->pStrides[i] = s_vertexBuffers.pStrides[i];
if (i != VERTEX_BUFFER::COLOR) 
{
   dataPtr->pStrides[i] *= total;
}
memcpy(dataPtr->pData[i], s_vertexBuffers.pData[i], dataPtr->pStrides[i]);
```

As you've found out when you have two pointers (say p and q) then all `p = q;` does is copy the pointer. If you want to copy the data that is being pointed to you should write `memcpy(p, q, size_of_data);`.

Comment: No john, what I want to do is directly point data in s_vertexBuffers into MappedResouce.pData without using memcpy and considering the size of buffers (pStrides) when copying it, I'm expecting and answer without using memcpy completely :)

Comment: @nesto Sorry I have no idea then.

Comment: @nesto You have effectively asked, "How do I copy data to the GPU, without copying any data?"